# mysql join two tables that one table is having multiple matching rows

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm trying to join two tables. lets say first table is test1 and other one is test2
in test1 table I have fields 
HOTEL_ID
NAME
CITY
COUNTRY

Then in the test2 table I have 
ROOM_ID
HOTEL_ID
ROOM_TYPE

so most of the time a hotel is having many type of rooms. so when I join these two tables using this query

```
$this->db->like('city', $visitingPlace);
$this->db->or_like('country', $visitingPlace);
$this->db->or_like('name', $visitingPlace);
$this->db->limit($per_page, $page);
$this->db->select('*')
         ->from('test1')
         ->join('test2', 'test1.hotel_id = test2.hotel_id', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

it is repeatedly showing the hotel name for each room type matching to that hotel id but I want to show hotel name once with all the room types. how can I achieve this?

Thank You

Comment: That's better done in PHP, doing it in codeigniter/activerecord will make for a comparatively complex query.

Comment: When you're showing the output, don't display the hotel name if it's the same as the previous row. Save the hotel name in a variable so you can compare it.

Comment: So what's the problem? You already have the hotel details and the rooms in the same result. Show the hotel details from the first row and show the rooms by iterating all the results. You don't have to change anything!

Answer (score 2):

The question is tagged "mysql", so here is a MySQL solution:

```
select h.*, group_concat(distinct room_type) as RoomTypes
from test1 h left join
     test2 r
     on h.hotel_id = r.hotel_id
group by h.hotel_id;
```

For each hotel, this will produce a column with a list of the room types at the hotel.

Comment: I tried this, but by this I can only take the room type from the second table. if I have more than one field that I want to get from the second table how can I do that?

Comment: @Yasitha . . . You should ask another question with sample data and desired results.  That will clarify what you are asking for.  Note:  if you edit this question you may invalidate the answers here, which is simply not nice.

Comment: If you know the way to do what I wanted please put as a comments

Answer (score 0):

You use the same query as it is just add order  by hotel id and in php use logic to show only once the hotel name for each group of rooms

```
$this->db->like('t1.city', $visitingPlace);
$this->db->or_like('t1.country', $visitingPlace);
$this->db->or_like('t1.name', $visitingPlace);
$this->db->limit($per_page, $page);
$this->db->select('t1.*,t2.ROOM_TYPE')
         ->from('test1 t1')
         ->join('test2 t2', 't1.hotel_id = t2.hotel_id', 'left')
->order_by('t1.hotel_id','ASC');
```

Fetch results from query

```
$results = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Loop through result store hotel id for each group of rooms and show only once

```
$currentParent = false;
foreach ($results as $r) {
    if ($currentParent != $r->hotel_id ) {
        echo '<h1>Hote Name ' . $r->name. '</h1>';
        $currentParent = $r->hotel_id;
    }
    echo '<p>' .$r->ROOM_TYPE. '</p>';
}
```

Sample output

```
<h1>Hote Name test1</h1>
    <p>room type 1</p>
    <p>room type 2</p>
<h1>Hote Name test 2</h1>
    <p> room type 3</p>
```

and so on